# Dynamic content plugin/module, depending on the site name

Tags: module, content, alias, t3-framework

Is there a plugin or module which shows content depending on the site I am currently on? For example:

- If I am on site with alias `site-1` I want picture `images/pictureXY.jpg` to be shown by the plugin/module.
- If I am on site with alias `site-2` I want text `Hello there` to be shown by the plugin/module.

Is there something similar out there? Or do I have to write one from scratch? It has to be a plugin/module because I am using T3 framework and want to enable/disable it depending on screen size.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me your question. What is the relationships between the sites?

Comment: I think the same Site get loaded on 2 different domains and it should display partly different content on each domain. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a way to install one extension in several sites, and  streamline some customization.

This plugin or module would be only for you to show fixed content under certain specific conditions:

- site-1 -> images/pictureXY.jpg
- site-2 -> Hello there

It is certainly possible, but you have to create it to hardcode the customizations according the site.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to make something that specific yourself. Basically, you can make a plugin or module that checks the current domain with an if-else statement:

```
if(strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'site1.com') == true){
    echo '<img src="images/pictureXY.jpg">';
} elseif (strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'site2.com') == true) {
    echo 'Hello there';
}
```